# PHP On error? browser downloads empty file

Tags: php, exec

I have a laravel/php script that runs the exec command:

```
$result = exec($command, $output);
return json_encode($output);
```

I know exec is dangerous (this is for testing).  When I load the page in a browser, the command takes a while and eventually the browser downloads and empty file:

[image]

If I comment out the exec command, the page outputs and empty array just fine.

When I use fiddler to see the response I get the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 31 Dec 2015 20:08:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8x
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/x-httpd-php
Content-Length: 0
```

This happens in Chrome and IE.

Comment: If the command takes a long time, you could be running into PHP's execution time limit.

Comment: Have you tried running the command and the php script from the command line and if so, does that work but also take a long time?

Comment: @Barmar 1) I use `set_time_limit(200)` and I get this error after 120 seconds.  2) I thought if php times out it returns 500.

Comment: @jeroen On the command line it takes about 20 seconds.